# Power automate - last of multiple items from outlook

Tags: power-automate

Quick question - I am trying to set it up so that when an e-mail arrives in a folder it creates a todo list. How do I get it such that it only does it for the last e-mail that is added. It seems to be replicating for each e-mail in the conversation rather than the latest one. In effect instead of value, I want: last(value)

Thanks in advance,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Add a to-do (v3)` without a loop. If a loop applied, it will apply the step to all the emails in the inbox.

[image]

It is tested, and works fine.

Make sure the Split On is enabled in the settings of the first step:

[image]

Comment: Whenever I add subject into the title bar it auto creates a for each box around it?

Comment: You should be able to enable Split On on the setting for the 'When a new email arrives (V3)', and then delete the last step and add the step again. It will not add the loop even if you add the subject again.

Comment: Really appreciate the help, but I still have my original issue. 

I made those changes, but when I test it, it creates a new task for each iteration within the conversation (I am using quicksteps to categorise e-mails as Do Today, Do Tomorrow etc. The quickstep makes a copy in the relevant folder, which triggers this flow). I only want this flow to trigger for the last element in the conversation. This might be an outlook rather than power automate issue

Comment: Yea, anyway as per your question you wanted to add the to do list for the last email, and the follow up comment on looping is fixed. So if its helped you sorting out the automate part, please accept the answer. Cheers.

Comment: Sadly, it hasn't. I really appreciate you taking the time to help. But despite your suggestion.  It still creates multiple entries despite the "for each" being removed, which was my main ask :/

Comment: Are you referring to the chain of emails from previous communication?

Comment: Yes, in outlook you have conversations where you have the original e-mail, then replies of that e-mail and so forth. The above recreates an entry for each e-mail within the conversation whereas I want it to be treated as one e-mail (or only the last e-mail)

Comment: you may try one of the methods suggested in here: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Extract-only-the-text-from-the-latest-reply-in-an-email-thread/td-p/122584